# How to create log file in akka.net?

Tags: nlog, akka.net

I'm learning akka.net and I struck here to implement logging with NLog. I have googled and checked the akka documents, but could not find the stuff. It will be great if anyone knows and could share the details.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you (See Readme.md):

https://github.com/AkkaNetContrib/Akka.Logger.NLog

Another guide:

http://gigi.nullneuron.net/gigilabs/actor-logging-with-akka-net/